# Tailwind classes not working with react after installation

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

The tailwind css classes are not displaying, i followed the installation process via tailwindcss.com create-react-app to install this. Cross-checked and i can't seem to find why it is still not working. i did update the react scripts to version 5.0.1 as instructed on an answer relating to this question but it did not solve the issue.

here is the package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "my-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

Tailwind.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```
function App() {
    return <div className="container mx_auto bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">
            <p className="text-5xl font-bold">
                Welcome
            </p>
            <p className="text-grey-500 text-lg">
                    React and Tailwind css updated now 
            </p>

    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you importing `index.css` anywhere?

Comment: imported index.css in the app.js and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @RobBailey I imported it but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help someone. So I had this issue that everything was installed correctly from the official docs from tailwind. But the styles were not being reflected.

When I say the whole installation went fine i really mean everything, like content inside the config, `tailwindcss, postcss, autoprefixer` and included the base tailwind

```
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;
```

styles in then `index.css`.

The issue on my end was I just had to update the react scripts with this command:

**`npm install react-scripts@latest`**

My previous version was `2.x` and after installation `5.x` was installed and everything is working fine now.

PS: And tailwind directives can be added either way, both works for me
Option 1 (I have gone with this one)

```
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;
```

OR
option 2

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Comment: This was the solution for me too - thank you

Comment: Tailwind CSS does not require React
 scripts to work. It is a utility-first CSS framework
 that can be used with any JavaScript library
 or framework
, including React. However, React is a popular choice for using Tailwind CSS because it allows you to create dynamic and visually appealing web applications
.  both tailwind and vite do not require 'react-scripts'

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall tailwind from devDependencies ...
   `npm uninstall <name of the modules> --save-dev`.
2. Install Tailwind on **dependencies**, *not devDependencies* (without the `-D`)

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

3. Follow the rest from official doc.

I've been practicing this for 7months it works like that

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
npm install postcss-flexbugs-fixes postcss-normalize postcss-preset-env
```

I had same problem and this line helped me.